# Updating custom field for devise user model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have a variable in my charges controller coming from a stripe response that I need to store in the customer_id field of a devise User object. I've added the migration to the User model for customer_id. I'm trying to use the update_attributes! method to store the stripe_customer_id variable in the customer_id field of the User object.

I have edited my application_controller to include strong params for my custom field (customer_id). I am successfully printing the stripe_customer_id string to the console, but once I try and pass that variable into customer_id and save it to the object, it doesn't save.

**charges_controller.rb** (Excerpt that is impacting the User model)

```
stripe_customer_id = customer.id
puts "-->#{stripe_customer_id}<--"          
if @charge.save 
  redirect_to gifts_path
  flash[:notice] = "It worked!"
  @user.update_attributes!(:customer_id => stripe_customer_id)
  puts "-->#{@user.customer_id}<--"
else 
  render 'charges/new'
  flash[:alert] = 'Something went wrong'
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :customer_id) }
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :charges
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Terminal SQL**

```
-->cus_3FGHqqW7cgnglX<--
SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "customer_id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 11  [["customer_id", 0], ["updated_at", Sat, 04 Jan 2014 03:45:46 UTC +00:00]]
-->0<--
```

Comment: I notice you're using update_attributes!. That should raise an exception if the attribute is not set correctly. Does it raise an exception?

Comment: By the way, I don't think your `configure_permitted_parameters` is necessary, since you are setting customer_id directly, not via mass-assignment.

Comment: @NickUrban It doesn't raise an exception. When I remove the '!' it still performs the same way. I just posted the output from the terminal.

Comment: It looks like it's working, setting `customer_id` to 0. When you query the users table, is customer_id not set to 0? When you print out `stripe_customer_id` is it not 0?

Comment: @NickUrban I just added the output if I print out stripe_customer_id it = "-->cus_3FGHqqW7cgnglX<--", so I know the variable is being set to the correct string. Then in the IF block, I try and set the customer_id field to -->cus_3FGHqqW7cgnglX<--, but when I print that out, I get -->0<--.. so It's not working like I need it to. Exactly, when I query the users table, customer_id is set to 0, not -->cus_3FGHqqW7cgnglX<--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customer_id` should be a string and not an integer in your database which it seems to be based on your seeing it always be set to 0

Comment: Solved the problem completely. Thank you for pointing out that mistake!

Comment: I know this one from experience :)